# chromatic number proof for $K_n$

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

So for proving chromatic number of $K_n$ is $n$, and I use the fact that the chromatic polynomial for $K_n$ is $\frac{k!}{(k-n)!}$, is it correct to state $n$ is the minimum number such that the chromatic polynomial has a value greater than $0$?

Negative factorials should not be a problem if I state that right?

Comment: The chromatic number is how many colors are needed to color the vertices of a graph so that no two adjacent vertices are the same color.  Since $K_n$ is the _____ graph on $n$ vertices, what is its chromatic number?

Comment: yes i know its complete i want to be consider using it's chromatic polynomial

Comment: Using the chromatic polynomial for this is using a pile driver to swat a mosquito, but yes, your statement is (almost) correct: $\chi(G)$ is the smallest **positive** integer that is not a root of the chromatic polynomial.

Comment: Okay, but $n$ is given, so we would not say $n$ is the minimum number such that $\ldots$ .

Comment: @hardmath: But in fact $n$ **is** the smallest positive integer that is not a zero of $t^{\underline n}$, the chromatic polynomial of $K_n$. The $n$ in $K_n$ is given, but the fact that it turns out to be the smallest positive integer that is not a zero of the chrom. poly. is not.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: True. I thought he was trying to state the condition of a non-root of the chromatic polynomial, which is univariate in $k$ as he wrote it.  Yes, that occurs at $k=n$.

Comment: @DJ_ Do you have a reason for wanting to do this using the chromatic polynomial rather than just by a very straightforward argument?

Comment: No just for fun..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The chromatic polynomial for $K_n$ is $P(K_n; t) = t^{\underline{n}} = t (t - 1) \ldots (t - n + 1)$ (a falling factorial power), then the minimal $t$ such that $P(K_n; t) \ne 0$ is $n$. Note that this is a polynomial in $t$ for all $n \ge 1$.

The falling factorial power can be expressed as $t^{\underline{n}} = \frac{t!}{(t - n)!}$, and it is usual to consider factorials of negative numbers to be infinite (this is consistent with the gamma function, $\Gamma(z) = \int_0^\infty u^{z - 1} e^{-u} du$, it is simple to check that for integer $n > 0$ it is $\Gamma(n) = (n - 1)!$). But that takes too far.

Comment: +1 for writing out the polynomial.  It is of course evident that this needs no "negative factorials" for its evaluation.   Further the "falling factorial" polynomial gives $n!$ as the count of valid colorings of $K_n$ using $k=n$ colors.

Answer (score 4):

Well think about what the chromatic polynomial is. Here you are GIVEN k colors and your chromatic polynomial gives you the number of ways of properly coloring your graph using these colors.

The chromatic number however is the MINIMUM number of colors needed to color your graph. So sure, if you were given the chromatic polynomial, you COULD find the smallest number n to make this polynomial defined, but I don't think it's necessary.

Just think about the complete graph. Since every pair of vertices is connected by an edge, then every vertex needs to be a different color, so the chromatic number is the number of vertices: n. No need to bring in the chromatic polynomial